# Looping through subreport elements java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I was able to get to elements in the report, but not to the subreports in it.

What is the best way to access the subreport elements to edit them from a JasperPrint instance?

Comment: Lets see your code on how to do this.

Comment: @Woot4Moo similar to this http://rocketscience.itteco.org/2010/04/03/custom-cell-coloring-in-the-jasperreports-crosstab-cell/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the solution that the subreports get added later on in the next iteration.

Comment: Yes, I am correct.  The correct subreport elements will be sent in the next iteration.